# .htaccess catching all invalid URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im pretty new to this, but according to my logic this should work.

What i want to do is catch all urls that do not match any rules before the end, and redirect them to error.php. If i try to access localhost/create or localhost/create/ it still redirects me to error.php. Am I missing something?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule    ^create/?$    create.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ error.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^create/?$ create.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ error.php [NC,L]
```

The problem with your rule is that it does not check if the file or folder exists so basically once it finds `create.php` it continues to the `error.php` because it was not asked to verify if the file existed.